# Rails error messages not appearing on website but showing in Chrome DevTools Network Preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to show error messages when creating a new instance of a model in my Rails app when a field doesn't pass validation. For some reason, the errors never actually show up on the website next to the fields like they're supposed to. *However, the errors appear in the 'Preview' section of the Network tab of Chrome DevTools.* So the errors are generating properly. In the terminal it says that `new.html.erb` is rendered but I don't think it actually does? Any help would be greatly appreciated - I haven't found much about this online. I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling the front end if that's helpful.

Here's my code:

**occasion.rb**

```
class Occasion < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :registries
    has_many :charities, :through => :registries
    
    validates :occasion_name, presence: true
    validates :occasion_date, presence: true
    validates :url, presence: true, format: { without: /\s/ }, uniqueness: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id

end
```

**occasions_controller.rb**

```
class OccasionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @occasions = Occasion.all
  end
  
  def show
    @occasion = Occasion.where(url: params[:url]).first
  end
  
  def new
    @occasion = Occasion.new
  end

  def create
    @occasion = Occasion.new(occasion_params)
    @occasion.user = current_user

    if @occasion.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to new_registry_path }
        format.js   { render :js => "window.location='#{ new_registry_path }'" }
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @occasion = Occasion.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @occasion = Occasion.find(params[:id])

    if @occasion.update(occasion_params)
      redirect_to @occasion
      return
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @occasion = Occasion.find(params[:id])
    @occasion.destroy

    redirect_to occasions_path
  end

  private
    def occasion_params
      params.require(:occasion).permit(:user_id, :occasion_name, :occasion_date, :url)
    end
    
  # user authentication is not required for show
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show]


end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: @occasion do |form| %>

    <div class="text-center">
        <%= form.label :occasion_name, "Occasion Name", class: "text-red-400 font-semibold px-8" %><br>
        <%= form.text_field :occasion_name, class: "rounded w-2/5" %>
        <% @occasion.errors.full_messages_for(:occasion_name).each do |message| %>
        <div><%= message %></div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center py-2">
        <%= form.label :occasion_date, "Occasion Date", class: "text-red-400 font-semibold px-8" %><br>
        <%= form.date_field :occasion_date, type: "date", class: "rounded" %>
        <% @occasion.errors.full_messages_for(:occasion_date).each do |message| %>
        <div><%= message %></div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center py-2">
        <%= form.label :url, 'URL', class: "text-red-400 font-semibold px-8" %><br>
        <%= form.text_field :url, class: "rounded" %>
        <% @occasion.errors.full_messages_for(:url).each do |message| %>
        <div><%= message %></div>
        <% end %>
        <em><div class="text-sm">domainname.com/yourURLhere</div></em>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center py-2">
        <%= form.submit occasion.persisted? ? 'Update' : 'Save', class: "rounded-full bg-red-400 text-white px-3" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks like the form gets submitted as an AJAX request. Can you check if `config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = true` is set in the project?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan What file in a Rails project would this be in? I don't see it anywhere in my project. I'm new to Rails - coming from Django. Thank you!

Comment: It should be added to `config/application.rb`. Anyway, looks like it's not added to the project configuration. This is unnecessary,  but try adding `local: true` to the `form_with` call (`form_with model: @occasion, local: true`). And can you share the server logs for the form submission request?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan That fixed it! Thank you!!! If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided information, it looks like the form gets submitted as an AJAX request. Since you're not passing `local: false` to the [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) call, there must be a configuration set to use AJAX form submissions by default.

From the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with),

> `:local` - By default form submits via typical HTTP requests. Enable remote and unobtrusive XHRs submits with `local: false`. Remote forms may be enabled by default by setting `config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms` = true.

Pass `local: true` to submit the request via a normal HTTP request.

```
<%= form_with model: @occasion, local: true do |form| %>
  <%#= ... %>
<% end %>
```